# Cannot export database in android : Failed to push selection: Local path doesn't exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I cannot export anymore my app database in Android Device Monitor. It was previously working before starting to fail. As you can see in the snapshot. the filename is laga1.db .

Tools:

- android studio 1.3.2
- Sqlite.
- Genymotion 2.5.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try doing it from command line

1. adb remount
2. su adb push filename path

If you trying to export ..then you need to do **adb pull**  and not **adb push**

Comment: Hi Rupesh  which filename path ? Database file ? where is it located ?

Comment: I guess you are trying to pull a file from device...try pull option which is located next to push option

Comment: I have successfully remount the adb but cannot pull the database file out.  Still getting the same error..

Comment: edited the answer...can you post the steps and the error too

Comment: Please which steps and error ?  " Failed to push selection: Local path doesn't exist " is the error I get in the console as you can see in picutre (bottom in red !)

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error as well. The solution is to close the application that is using the database.
You can easily do that in the process list. Just select the application that is using it (probably just the app you are developing) and press the stop button.

[image: process list]

After that you can pull the database file.
This probably happens because the database is opened in ready-only in the application.